# SQL Server pivot table Help101

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a data in SQL Server with dates and gender counts

```
WC         Gender   Cnt
-----------------------
2017-01-02  M   84617
2017-01-02  F   54896
2017-01-09  M   60120
2017-01-09  F   40173
2017-01-16  M   56387
2017-01-16  F   41164
```

I have data in this format and I need to transform it into

```
WC          M       F
--------------------------
02/01/2017  84617   54896
09/01/2017  60120   40173
16/01/2017  56387   41164
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
select
    wc
  , M = max(case when gender = 'M' then Cnt end)
  , F = max(case when gender = 'F' then Cnt end)
from t
group by wc
```

Using `pivot()`

```
select 
    wc 
  , M
  , F
from t
  pivot (max(cnt) for gender in (m,f)) as p
```

Both return:

```
+------------+-------+-------+
|     wc     |   M   |   F   |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2017-01-02 | 84617 | 54896 |
| 2017-01-09 | 60120 | 40173 |
| 2017-01-16 | 56387 | 41164 |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ITC17758

Answer (score 0):

No Pivot needed.  You can do this with a couple of joins...

```
SELECT a.wc, t1.cnt, t2.cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT wc FROM tablename) a
INNER JOIN tablename t1 ON t1.wc = a.wc AND t1.gender = 'M'
INNER JOIN tablename t2 ON t2.wc = a.wc AND t2.gender = 'F'
```